# excel formula for working handling two different tax brackets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm making a spreadsheet in excel to help me understand how starting a part-time business on top of my full time job might affect my tax. I need to do this because I'm very close to my next UK tax bracket and I want to know exactly how it might affect my finances.

As part of this I'm trying to write an excel formula that will add two numbers then check if this new number is  greater than a third number. I will refer to the two numbers added together as A and the third number as B. If A is not greater than B then I will multiply by 20% to find out how much of it is owed in tax. If A is greater than B I will subtract B from A to create number C and multiply B by 20% and C by 40% and add the two together to produce the final number I need. Can someone please xplain to me how to script this in Excel? I've looked for online examples but I'm not finding the language very penetrable. If I was using a scripting language I was more familiar with the code would look like this:

```
  float taxThreshold = 42011.00;
  int income = foo;

  if(taxThreshold < income)
  {
    float higherRate = income-taxThreshold;
    float standardTaxOwed = taxThreshold * 20%;
    float higherRateOwed = higherRate * 40%;
    float finalTaxOwed = standardTaxOwed+higherTaxOwed;
  }
  else
  {
    float finalTaxOwed = income * 20%;
  }
```

I'm sure this is very simple to do, I just don't get the excel syntax. Can someone show me how this should be done? You'd not only be solving this problem but also giving me a means of translating from my current scripting knowledge into excel.

Comment: Peter's answer shows the general approach: anything that would be a variable in a conventional language becomes a separate cell (that you can name if desired) in Excel. You *could* wrap it all up into a single calc, but you don't gain anything by doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to store your 4 input parameters in some cells - and then name them. To do so, select the cell and type a meaningful name into the field that shows the address (i.e. left of the formula bar).

Once you have done this, you can simply use this formula:

```
=IF(Income>Threshold,Threshold*StandardTaxRate+(Income-Threshold)*HighTaxRate,Income*StandardTaxRate)
```

Without the naming, the formula would be something like this:

```
=IF(B2>B1,B1*B7+(B2-B1)*B8,B2*B7)
```

Both formulas will calculate you the tax you'd need to pay. If you want it more explicit, I'd recommend a layout such as this:

[image]

The formulas would read:

```
C7: =IF(B2>B1,B1,B2)
C8: =IF(B2>B1,B2-B1,0)
D7: =B7*C7
D8: =B8*C8
```

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very clear and helpful in terms of the problem and also makes excel syntax more understandable. Cheers!